# What notation is available for denoting paths up to homotopy?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, contour-integration, homotopy-theory

Suppose we delete two points from the complex plane, call them $p$ and $q$. Call the resulting space $X$. We're looking for notation for paths from a point $a \in X$ to a point $b \in X$ that's specific enough that we know exactly how we're twisting around the points $p$ and $q$, to get from $a$ to $b$, but not so specific that we have to actually define the path up to equality.

> **Question.** Is there good notation for this kind of thing, where we wish to denote paths up to homotopy only?
>
> I'm interested both in the specific case where all we're dealing with is the plane minus a few points, and also in the more general case where we're dealing with an arbitrary manifold.

This could be useful for denoting contour integrals, for example.

Comment: What is preventing you from choosing an appropriate notation? It is not clear what you mean by "how we're twisting... up to equality."

Comment: Denote a curve from $a$ to $b$ by $\gamma^i_j(a,b)$, where the curve completes $i$ closed loops around point $p$ and $j$ closed loops around point $q$? I'm not quite sure what you mean by how they're twisting, but loops around the points should determine which paths are homotopic to other paths to a large extent.

Comment: Since $\pi_1(\mathbb R^2\smallsetminus\{\ast^1,\ast^2\})$ is $\mathbb Z\ast \mathbb Z$, you can use words in $a$ and $b$ and their inverses.

Comment: A standard notation for the fundamental groupoid of a space  $X$ is $\pi_1(X)$ so those from $p$ to $q$ are written $\pi_1(X)(p,q)$ while the fundamental groupoid on the set $p,q$ of base points is written $\pi_1(X,\{p,q\})$. In the book . Topology and Groupoids $\pi_1(X)$ is written $\pi X$. Also the set of paths on $X$ is written $PX$ and this becomes a category under composition by using paths of length $r$ for all $r \geqslant 0$.